# How to manually add a cookie to Mechanize state?

Tags: ruby, cookies, mechanize

I'm working in Ruby, but my question is valid for other languages as well.

I have a Mechanize-driven application.  The server I'm talking to sets a cookie using JavaScript (rather than standard set-cookie), so Mechanize doesn't catch the cookie.  I need to pass that cookie back on the next GET request.

The good news is that I already know the value of the cookie, but I don't know how to tell Mechanize to include it in my next GET request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These answers are old, so to bring this up to date, these days it looks more like this:

```
cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new :domain => '.mydomain.com', :name => name, :value => value, :path => '/', :expires => (Date.today + 1).to_s
agent.cookie_jar << cookie
```

Comment: Thanks, @pguardiario.  Giving you the checkmark since my answer had become stale.

Answer (score 32):

I figured it out by extrapolation (and reading sources):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
...
cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new(key, value)
cookie.domain = ".oddity.com"
cookie.path = "/"
agent.cookie_jar.add(cookie)
...
page = agent.get("https://www.oddity.com/etc")
```

Seems to do the job just fine.

### update

As @Benjamin Manns points out, Mechanize now wants a URL in the `add` method.  Here's the amended recipe, making the assumption that you've done a GET using the agent, and that the last page visited is the domain for the cookie (saves a `URI.parse()`):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
...
cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new(key, value)
cookie.domain = ".oddity.com"
cookie.path = "/"
agent.cookie_jar.add(agent.history.last.uri, cookie)
```

Comment: Note: Now you must pass a URI like `agent.cookie_jar.add(URI.parse('www.oddity.com', cookie)`.

Comment: @BenjaminManns would be nice to correct your comment to `agent.cookie_jar.add(URI.parse('www.oddity.com'), cookie)`

Comment: When you use a destructive method, you don't have to pass a URI! `agent.cookie_jar.add!(cookie)`

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add my experience for specifically passing cookies from [Selenium](https://github.com/vertis/selenium-webdriver) to Mechanize:

Get the cookies from your selenium driver

```
sel_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
sel_driver.navigate.to('https://sample.com/javascript_login')
#login
sel_cookies = sel_driver.manage.all_cookies
```

Value for `:expires` from Selenium cookie is a `DateTime` object or blank.

However, value for `:expires` Mechanize cookie (a) must be a string and (b) cannot be blank

```
sel_cookies.each do |c|
  if c[:expires].blank?
    c[:expires] = (DateTime.now + 10.years).to_s #arbitrary date in the future
  else
    c[:expires] = c[:expires].to_s
  end
end
```

Now instantiate as Mechanize cookies and place them in the cookie jar

```
mech_agent = Mechanize.new
sel_cookies.each { |c| agent.cookie_jar << Mechanize::Cookie.new(c) }
mech_agent.get 'https://sample.com/html_pages'
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this

```
Mechanize::Cookie.parse(url, "SessionCookie=#{sessid}", 
  Logger.new(STDOUT)) { |c| agent.cookie_jar.add(url, c) }
```

source: http://twitter.com/#!/calebcrane/status/51683884341002240

Answer (score 0):

```
response.to_hash.fetch("set-cookie").each do |c|
  agent.cookie_jar.parse c
end
```

`response` here is a native Ruby stdlib thing, like Net::HTTPOK.